# Selecting field from other foreign table via foreign key

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

I'm using CodeIgniter, PHP and MySQL in my website.

I have a database that contains 2 tables. A `ftp_settings` table and a `users` table.
In my `ftp_settings` there is a field `user_id` that is a foreign key to the `user_id` field in the `users` table. I'm trying to get the `user_email` field from the users table via the `ftp_settings` table its `user_id` field.

I've read I should use a SQL JOIN statement to achieve this, however my code keeps producing errors.

Please note I'm fairly new to SQL, PHP and CodeIgniter.

**Visual representation:**
[image: Database structure]

**My current code:**

```
            $this->db->select('ftp_settings.user_id');
            $this->db->from('ftp_settings');
            $this->db->join('users','ftp_settings.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

***TL;DR :***
I'm using CodeIgniter that uses 2 tables. ftp_settings and users. I need the user_email field in the users table via the ftp_settings user_id foreign key.

How am I able to achieve this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting? It might be helpful to see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join looks perfect but you have selected only the user_id you also need to select the email field

```
$this->db->select('ftp_settings.user_id , users.user_email');
$this->db->from('ftp_settings');
$this->db->join('users','ftp_settings.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

[**Have a look at Active Record**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 1):

I don´t work with codeigniter but i think this should work

```
$this->db->select('ftp_settings.user_id, users.user_email');
$this->db->from('ftp_settings');
$this->db->join('users','ftp_settings.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        $this->db->select('users.user_email');
        $this->db->from('ftp_settings');
        $this->db->join('users','ftp_settings.user_id = users.user_id', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
```